# Trouble with app permissions in Germany cloud

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I've converted my app to no longer use the Discovery service, and only the Graph API, so that it can work in the Germany cloud (https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/663#issuecomment-349127273). The app is working correctly in the standard cloud, but not in the Germany cloud. I believe it is a permissions issue.

Specifically, the authorization steps seem to all be okay, and I can successfully access https://graph.microsoft.de/v1.0/me

```
{
       "@odata.context" => "https://graph.microsoft.de/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
                   "id" => "blah",
       "businessPhones" => [],
          "displayName" => "...",
            "givenName" => "...",
             "jobTitle" => nil,
                 "mail" => "...",
          "mobilePhone" => nil,
       "officeLocation" => nil,
    "preferredLanguage" => "en-us",
              "surname" => "...",
    "userPrincipalName" => "..."
}
```

But I get a 404 error for https://graph.microsoft.de/v1.0/me/drive

```
{
    "error" => {
              "code" => "UnknownError",
           "message" => "404 FILE NOT FOUND",
        "innerError" => {
            "request-id" => "f35e17ff-b248-47cd-a81c-69c38275b1da",
                  "date" => "2018-03-01T22:41:13"
        }
    }
}
```

One other thing I noticed: when going through the login flow for graph.microsoft.com, it includes going to https://login.microsoft.com/common/oauth2/authorize (I think that's the url, anyway), where the user is prompted to allow certain permissions. I never see that page come up for the Germany cloud.

Our admin looked at the app configuration in the microsoft developer console, and it certainly seems to have the permissions it would need to access the user's drive:

- SharePoint Online --> Read and write user files
- Microsoft Graph --> Have full access to all files user can access

Is there a way for me to verify what permissions I have access to (via the API)? What other options do I have to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Welp... It looks like this was probably just an error on my part, though I'm not entirely certain.

I noticed that I was constructing the URL incorrectly:

https://graph.microsoft.de/v1.0/me/drive

should have been

https://graph.microsoft.de/v1.0/drive

But it seemed to be working in the global cloud, just not in the Germany cloud, so I'm still a bit confused about that.